# Does SLD tree exist if the query is invalid in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Considering the following Prolog program :

```
reverse_bits([1], [0]).
reverse_bits([0], [1]).
reverse_bits([H|T], [0|R]) :- H==1, reverse_bits(T, R).
reverse_bits([H|T], [1|R]) :- H==0, reverse_bits(T, R).
```

What's the SLD tree for the question above ?

```
reverse_bits(Input, [1, 0, 0]).?
```

It's not valid so does it even exist a SLD tree ?

Comment: why do you think that it is invalid? it isn't; that's a perfectly valid query which happens to fail. so the SLD tree exists, is fully explored, and not solutions are found.

Comment: Replace the `==` by `=`.  `(==)/2` is a meta-logical predicate. Then you get your SLD tree

Comment: @WillNess Yes , you are right this query is valid but it fails.

Comment: @false Is there any online tool that visualizes the SLD tree of a query ?

Comment: There is a swi package: sldnfdraw

Comment: Actually the SLD tree (the **proof tree** using proof-by-contradiction and resolution in a fragment of first order classical logic) does not exist because as *false* noted, there is an `==` in there, which makes no sense in that setting. The **call tree** in an operational setting using unification and left-to-right call order (barring the occasional [`freeze/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=freeze/2) and other magic), trying to return `true` ("a proof by confirmation"?) along all branches and vaguely working in a fragment of intuitionistic first-order logic does well exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a minimal example using the `sldnfdraw` package. First, generate a program and query using the syntax specified in the [library documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=sldnfdraw):

```
% estamos.pl

:- use_module(library(sldnfdraw)).
:- sldnf.

:- begin_program.

reverse_bits([1], [0]).
reverse_bits([0], [1]).
reverse_bits([H|T], [0|R]) :- H==1, reverse_bits(T, R).
reverse_bits([H|T], [1|R]) :- H==0, reverse_bits(T, R).

:- end_program.

:- begin_query.

reverse_bits(Input,[1,0,0]).

:- end_query.
```

Next, generate a `.tex` file for the relevant resolution tree:

```
?- draw_goal('estamos-tree.tex').
```

You can run this goal from the command line. Finally, include this file in a `.tex` document

```
% estamos-tree-draw.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epic,eepic}
\usepackage{ecltree}
\begin{document}
\input{estamos-tree}
\end{document}
```

and compile with

```
$ latex estamos-tree-draw.tex
$ dvipdf estamos-tree-draw.dvi
```

There should be a `.pdf` file in your source folder containing the resolution tree.

## Code improvement

For what it's worth I would suggest writing your program as:

```
reverse_bits([],[]).
reverse_bits([0|T],[1|R]) :- reverse_bits(T,R).
reverse_bits([1|T],[0|R]) :- reverse_bits(T,R).
```

for simplicity and to avoid using `==` in place of unification, as **false** noted in the comments.

## Output when using `=` (unification)

Here we use `=` unification in the "guard part" testing `H`.

[image: SLD tree with unification]

## Output when using `==` (term equivalence)

When using [term equivalence](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%3D)/2) `==` we are done really quickly because there is failure at the first call:

[image: SLD tree with term equivalence]

Because the only clause that matches is `reverse_bits([H|T], [1|R]) :- H==0, reverse_bits(T, R).` and at that point, `H` is a fresh variable and in no way equivalent to `0`.

Comment: This is neat! I tried this on Fedora 30. Output added!

Comment: While all of this is great, one more step to make the use of the image more useful would be to convert it to SVG which all common Internet browsers support and is also scalable, See: LaTeX/Export To Other Formats [Vector graphics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Export_To_Other_Formats#Vector_graphics)

Comment: @false Actually like [this](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/free1/uploads/swiprolog/original/1X/1e28f220827870b62050f7f235a4cf58d689db83.svg), a true SVG.  Another [example](https://logtalk.org/diagrams/cliopatria/html_basics_module_xref_diagram.svg) generated with Logtalk.

Comment: @GuyCoder: causa finita: Failed to upload image; the format is not supported. So SVG is just as non-portable as EPS was/is

Comment: Another site to consider when creating notes on Prolog and wanting to add graphics would be use use [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/). [This](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/truncated-image-rendering-with-svgtree-in-swish/813) might be of help