# how to draw a search tree using trace in prolog

Tags: prolog, trace

I am struggling to draw a search tree using trace in prolog any ideas on how to do this?

here is what I have when I do trace:

```
[trace]  ?- rabbit_owner(N).
   Call: (8) rabbit_owner(_7256) ? creep
   Call: (9) street(_7472) ? creep
   Call: (10) _7458=[_7458, _7464, _7470, _7476] ? creep
   Exit: (10) [[[[[[[[[...|...]|...], _7464|...], _7464, _7470|...], _7464, _7470, _7476], _7464, _7470, _7476], _7464, _7470, _7476], _7464, _7470, _7476], _7464, _7470, _7476]=[[[[[[[[[...|...]|...], _7464|...], _7464, _7470|...], _7464, _7470, _7476], _7464, _7470, _7476], _7464, _7470, _7476], _7464, _7470, _7476], _7464, _7470, _7476] ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(house(black, _7484, _7486), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], _7464|...], _7464, _7470|...], _7464, _7470, _7476], _7464, _7470, _7476], _7464, _7470, _7476], _7464, _7470, _7476]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) lists:member(house(black, _7484, _7486), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), _7470|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), _7470, _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), _7470, _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), _7470, _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), _7470, _7476]) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(house(blue, _7492, _7494), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), _7470|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), _7470, _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), _7470, _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), _7470, _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), _7470, _7476]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) lists:member(house(blue, _7492, _7494), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), _7476]) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(house(brown, _7500, _7502), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), _7476], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), _7476]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) lists:member(house(brown, _7500, _7502), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(house(black, french, _7510), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, _7484, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) lists:member(house(black, french, _7486), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, _7486), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(house(_7514, spanish, jaguar), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, _7486), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, _7492, _7494), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) lists:member(house(blue, spanish, jaguar), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, _7486), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(house(_7522, _7524, rabbit), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, _7486), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, _7486), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) lists:member(house(black, french, rabbit), [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Call: (10) sublist([house(_7536, _7538, snail), house(_7550, japanese, _7554)], [[[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Call: (11) suffix(_7572, [[[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Call: (12) lists:append(_7572, _7574, [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Exit: (12) lists:append([], [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) suffix([[[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], [[[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Call: (11) prefix([house(_7536, _7538, snail), house(_7550, japanese, _7554)], [[[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Call: (12) lists:append([house(_7536, _7538, snail), house(_7550, japanese, _7554)], _7574, [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ? creep
   Fail: (12) lists:append([house(_7536, _7538, snail), house(_7550, japanese, _7554)], _7574, [[[[[[[[...|...]|...], house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(..., ..., ...)|...], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(..., ..., ...)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)], house(black, french, rabbit), house(blue, spanish, jaguar), house(brown, _7500, _7502)]) ?
```

but I don't know how to convert it into the search tree, One thing I am confused about is whether everything that has 10 would be on the same line or not..
any help is appreciated please. 
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: `One thing I am confused is on whether everything that has 10 would be on the same line or not` Yes it should be on the same *level*.

Comment: While you can continue to ask Q&A type question at StackOverflow, perhaps you would prefer a discussion format. While StackOverflow does have rooms for discussions, you would be better served by starting this as a topic at the SWI-Prolog [forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/) If you start a new topic there now, don't expect an answer until tomorrow as this is probably the slowest time of the week to get responses on any of these sites.

Comment: See [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59692569/772868). It uses